# Can numpy array be accessed using an indexing object?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Please assume

```
a = np.zeros((4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

I can access or slice the array like so

```
element = a[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sub_array = a[1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:4, 1:6]
```

I would like to dynamically, separately create the `2, 3, 4, 5, 6` or `1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:4, 1:6` part, then access `a` with it.

Something such as

```
b = 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, 1:4, 1:6
a[b]
```

Is that supported in numpy?

Comment: "I can access or slice the array like so" … both of the pieces of code you added after that raise exceptions with your given `a`, so it's not clear what you mean by `can`.

Comment: Did you mean `np.zeros((4, 5, 6, 7, 8))` or something like this?

Comment: @Mark `can` means I want to *separately* create the `2, 3, 4, 5`, such as `b = 2, 3, 4, 5, ` then `a[b]`

Comment: @Gulzar, you actually can do exactly that: `b = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and then `a[b]`, given that `a` is 5-dimensional

Comment: @Gulzar it's not clear what `a[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` means here because it raises an error. This makes it hard to know what you actually want to do. The code in your question needs to be runnable — if python can't make sense of it, we probably can't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = np.zeros((4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
b = slice(1,2), slice(1, 3), slice(1,4), slice(1, 4), slice(1,6)
a[b]
```

gives the following:

```
array([[[[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]],


    [[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]]]])
```

and

```
a = np.zeros((4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
c = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
a[c]
```

gives:

```
0.0
```

Is this what you're looking for?